# How can I align my images in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am writing a script that will insert an image at the cursor of my TinyMCE textarea.  I want to be able to add the align attribute to this image.  Everything goes smoothly until I add the align attribute.  The images I insert always have an alignment of left, no matter what option I choose in my modal.

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('article-content');                // get editor instance
                        var range = ed.selection.getRng();                  // get range
                        var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement ( "img" );  // create img node
                        newNode.src=attachment.prop('src');    
                        newNode.width = attachment.width();
                        newNode.height = attachment.height();
                        newNode.align = $('input[name="align"]').val();                                           // add src attribute
                        range.insertNode(newNode);      
                        /* Clear previous values */                                     
                        $('input[name="align"]').prop('checked', false);


<input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="align" value="left"> Left
<input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="align" value="center"> Center
<input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" name="align" value="right"> Right
```